# How do I open a chrome-extension popup only under a single circumstance?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension on my toolbar that, when clicked, will turn the current page into the google cached version of that page. If I am already on a google Cache of a page, I want to open a little popup saying, "You're already on the google cache version of this page!"

Here's what I got:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "gCache",
  "version": "1.1.5",
  "description": "View the Google Cache of a page",
  "background_page": "redirect.html",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_text": "Google Cache version of this page"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

redirect.html:

```
<script>

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (tab.url.substring(0, 38) == "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/")
        //Popup saying user is already on a webcache page
    else if(tab.url.substring(0, 5) == "http:")
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:' + tab.url.substr(7) });
    else if(tab.url.substring(0,6) == "https:")
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:' + tab.url.substr(8) });

});

</script>
```

Thank you for reading and for helping!

Comment: You could use a content script to show a JS `alert()` -- I think using a Desktop Notification is the better user experience for the user.

Comment: @JasonHall I won't use a JS `alert()` because it's annoying. I want to use the popup feature of chrome extensions. However, it is starting to look like the functionality for what I want to do just doesn't exist

Comment: It does exist, I'm just not sure there's a good way to only show the popup sometimes. You could try having the popup always show then immediately close, it might do it fast enough that it works, but I kind of doubt it. Or, you could make your extension a Page Action instead of a Browser Action, so the icon won't appear at all on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix and match `browserAction` `onClick` events with opening a popup. You may want to use the [Desktop Notifications API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/) instead.

Comment: I don't think the Desktop Notifications API is useful here. Is there a reason why I cannot have "browser_action": { "default_popup": } enabled too?

Comment: You could have the notifications auto hide after five seconds or something like that. Google designed it this way: `Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup.`. https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked